# MySQL - find and fix incorrect characters

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters

I have a table in MySQL that contains people's names and now some people are putting in characters with accents. Whatever original character set/collation this database used, it could not handle characters with accents and characters. Characters such as 'é' turned into 'Ã©', characters such as 'ü' turned into 'Ã¼' in the front-end applications that connect to this database. The database has since been modified (as well as most front-end applications that needed it) so that these fields use a UTF8 encoding and collation. Most names with accents now render correctly.

The problem is, there are some fields that now have a *literal* 'Ã©' (some weird double-encoding caused by manually copying and pasting stuff? I don't know, I wasn't there!). I now need to find all of these and modify these fields to use the correct accented characters. To find them, I wrote a query (based on the table I found [here](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html#dbg)):

```
select count(*), bad_char
from some_table
inner join (
  select 'â‚¬' as bad_char union
  select 'â€š' as bad_char union
  select 'Æ’' as bad_char union
  select 'â€ž' as bad_char union
  select 'â€¦' as bad_char union
  ...
  -- snip a whole bunch
  ...
  select 'Ã¾' as bad_char union
  select 'Ã¿' as bad_char ) bad_chars
where some_table.some_text_field like CONCAT('%',bad_chars.bad_char,'%')
group by bad_char
order by count(*);
```

And I get results like this:

```
count(*), bad_char
------------------
'1',     'Â¯'
'1',     'Ã‘'
'1',     'Ã–'
'1',     'Å½'
'1',     'Ã‡'
'1',     'Â¬'
...snip...
'1797',  'ÃŸ'
'4450',  'ÃŠ'
```

But I have a feeling this doesn't quite work the way I think it does. One of the "bad_char" combinations I'm searching for is 'ÃŠ' but when I run a query like this:

```
select some_text_field from some_table where some_text_field like '%ÃŠ%';
```

I get many results that are 'as' which are the same letters but without the accents. But for other cases such as 'Â¯' the query seems to work fine.

How can I get this query to *not* treat 'as' the same as 'ÃŠ'?

Comment: Depending on how big your database is, I’d probably just dump the content, replace the characters in the resulting SQL file in a text editor, and then upload it again …

Comment: @CBroe: Probably too big for that. And I'd really rather keep this sort of thing in the database rather than write a whole bunch of scripts to extract to a file, transform, and reload.

Comment: Well that "whole bunch of scripts" exists already - phpmyadmin, or if you want it even smaller, adminer (that is a nifty little one-file database admin interface.)

Comment: Please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...` so we can see what was stored.  Plus provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  From those we can decide whether you have "double encoding" and/or whether your data is so mangled after the attempted fix that it can't be repaired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get many results that are 'as' which are the same letters but without the accents.

That would be an issue of the [*collation*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-general.html) used - those are rule sets for character comparison, and they define which characters are to be treated as equal in different languages.

But you can use the [`BINARY`operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-binary-op.html) to change that directly within the query.

Answer (score 1):

For Mojibake ('é' turned into 'Ã©'), the fix for the *data* is

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(...) ...;
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(...) ... CHARACTER SET utf8 ...;
```

Your `SELECTs` sound like Mojibake -- `â‚¬` should have been `€`, correct?

The fix for the *code* is to understand that

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8`, but it should have been that.

The `SET NAMES` is often done by language-specific code; what programming language are you using.

Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see what `CHARACTER SET` you are using.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else trying to fix broken UTF8 accented text on latin1 fields, when some of them have proper latin1 and others have broken UTF8, the solution is this:

```
update posts set post_text = @txt where length(post_text) = length(@txt := convert(binary post_text using utf8));
```

This will fix only those rows with wrongly encoded UTF8 back into proper latin1 encoding, and `Ã¡` will become `á`, etc.